# CS0436 Error show in Asp.net when i import a project

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I import an ASP.NET website and runs this message occurs:

> **CS0436**    The type `Home` in `Home.aspx.cs` conflicts with the imported type `Home` in `App_Web_whugun0o, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null`. Using the type defined in
>   `Home.aspx.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Home.aspx.cs` by renaming with different name.